# What permissions are required for "Run Script" during a build phase?

Tags: xcode, build, permission-denied, run-script

In the "Run Script" build phase of my project, everything works if I type in the script into the text box for "run script" in build phases.

But to make editing / diffing etc easier, I thought I would save the script as a file as part of my project, and just fill in the path in the text box instead:

Eg: I paste the following path in the text box.

```
/Users/superman/Documents/Projects/SomeProject/scriptname.sh
```

But when I try to build this, I get a "Permission Denied" message.

What can I do to fix this? If I cut/paste the actual code, then it just "works". My user account is an administrator account. No one else uses my machine.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can simplify your Xcode project file a little further and not require the "bin/sh " in front of the script name.

To avoid this, you need to turn on "execute" permissions for users (Xcode in this case) of the file.

Steps

- Go into terminal
- Navigate to where your script is
- run `chmod 755 yourScriptName.sh`

Comment: I think this answer should be marked as correct because it is addressing the core of the issue. A runnable script file should be marked as executable.

Comment: simple but effective :)

Comment: That saved my time!

Answer (score 39):

Put `/bin/sh` in front of the path to the script name.

```
/bin/sh /Users/superman/Documents/Projects/SomeProject/scriptname.sh
```

Answer (score 15):

Just use

```
chmod u+x nameofscript.sh
```

Thats it .

Answer (score 1):

Simple Steps:

1. Go to the `<your_Script>.sh` via `cd <Your_Path_To_.sh_File>`
2. Run `chmod +x <your_file>.sh`

Thats it