# Is it possible to update a localized storyboard's strings?

Tags: ios, xcode, string, localization, storyboard

I localized a part of my application with creating a base.lproj storyboard and 3 string files for it. It was a month ago and after that I added new view controller to app, but this controller's buttons and labels not appear in string files

Is it possible to update this 3 storyboard attached string files or I must add new strings translations programmatically with using NSLocalizableString and Localizable.strings?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/

Answer (score 272):

There are two options:

### Option 1

Xcode can "reload" the file by converting the file to either an **[Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Storyboard]** file type or a **[Localizable Strings]** file type.

1. Select your base storyboard file from the Project Navigator
2. Find the *Localization* section in the File Inspector
3. If your file is currently a [Localizable Strings], change it to [Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Storyboard] or vice-versa.
4. Xcode should have converted your storyboard to the current version, while preserving your old localization efforts. Here you can change the file back to the original file type if you would like.

### Option 2

Use ibtool to extract the strings in your storyboard.

1. Open the Terminal application
2. Locate your Base.lproj directory
3. Use this line to extract the strings:

   `ibtool MainStoryboard.storyboard --generate-strings-file file_name.strings`
4. After ibtool extracts the strings to file_name.strings, you can copy and paste it to your original .strings file

Visit for more info: https://conyac.cc/business/columns/localization_guide_ios

Comment: I tried Option 1, but changing the file type from [Localizable Strings] to [Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Storyboard] results always in a crash of Xcode 5.0.1. The reason might be that - because I was not aware of the possibilities above - I edited the storyboard localization files by hand earlier.

Comment: Option 1 works.but you need to change from "Localizable .." to "interface ..." and then back again!

Comment: Build your project first otherwise Option 1 does not work for recently added elements

Comment: option 1 worked for me before. now I added a new view and when I try to use this technique it converts to strings without a problem, except it uses the old version. (without my new added view). when I change those strings back in to a storyboard, it messes up something, the result is storyboad that contains stuff from 2 different languages randomly. Like one button says : hello, other bonjour, when both of them should have bonjour on them

Comment: i tried option 2, no problem in changing and translating strings. but the problem is, my storyboard didnt change, i only changed the texts manually, it didnt add a new view in my app when i run it on another language

Comment: Option 3 (Actually, the option I found most maintainable for me): Keep all your text inside .strings files. I found that I needed to frequently grab the labels to change the font sizes and style depending on the language anyways, so it worked out best for me to keep all text out of the storyboards and just use the .string files.

Comment: Option 1 worked for me (not in the beginning, first crashed) but after cleaning derived Data, worked.

Comment: Option 1 doesn't work for me using XCode 6.0.1. When trying to convert my .strings file to .interfacebuilder XCode asks if the files should be converted. The files get created on the file system, however the string files still remain and contain the old values.

Comment: @ThaLeang I would replace the order of options. Option 2 seems more reliable. And reliability is what we need when we can loose all translation by mistake...

Comment: For me Option 1 replaced all already translated strings with English ones. I had to add the translation once again.

Comment: Option 1 seems very unstable in Xcode 7. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes it randomly replaces some of my already translated strings with english versions again.

Comment: Option 1 was good, but doesn't work anymore after using "refactor to storyboard".

Comment: I created a command line utility that automates a similar approach to option 2. You can integrate it as a build script which allows you to forget about updating your `.strings` files, instead of manually updating them each time you make a change as described here. See my answer for further details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35398661/3451975 I hope you like it!

Comment: how to generate strings for Settings.bundle?

Comment: You need to translate the whole file again with 1 option!

Comment: Option 2 went smoothly

Answer (score 88):

Check out **[ReMafoX](https://remafox.app)**, it's a Mac app that perfectly solves your problem. It can be **easily installed and integrated** within your project, watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ObGIiWARjmw&list=PLvkAveYAfY4TLPtPd5jnqMwpAzY_pdxs5&index=1) for a detailed walkthrough.

Alternatively, if you prefer an open source CLI tool without a GUI, you can also use [BartyCrouch](https://github.com/FlineDev/BartyCrouch).

---

**Install** BartyCrouch via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh):

```
brew install bartycrouch
```

Alternatively, install it via [Mint](https://github.com/yonaskolb/Mint):

```
mint install Flinesoft/BartyCrouch
```

**Incrementally update** your Storyboards/XIBs Strings files:

```
$ bartycrouch update
```

This will do exactly what you were looking for.

---

In order to **keep** your Storyboards/XIBs Strings files **updated over time** I highly recommend adding a build script (instructions on how to add a build script [here](https://github.com/Flinesoft/BartyCrouch#build-script)):

```
if which bartycrouch > /dev/null; then
    bartycrouch update -x
    bartycrouch lint -x
else
    echo "warning: BartyCrouch not installed, download it from https://github.com/Flinesoft/BartyCrouch"
fi
```

In addition to incrementally updating your Storyboards/XIBs Strings files this will also **make sure your `Localizable.strings` files stay updated** with newly added keys in code using `NSLocalizedString` and show warnings for duplicate keys or empty values.

Make sure to checkout BartyCrouch on [GitHub](https://github.com/Flinesoft/BartyCrouch) or [this detailed article](https://medium.com/@Dschee/localization-in-swift-like-a-pro-48164203afe2) for additional information.

Comment: Wow! This tool is simply amazing. This needs more upvotes!

Comment: lovely tool - no more manual copy/pasting of new label-texts in *.strings-files (...and forgetting any new label's translation as before)... Thanks a lot !

Comment: is there a similar pod for OBJC projects?

Comment: This is the answer we are looking for. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I don't get why after 6 years since this question is asked and this patchy solution is still required to get this to work in Xcode. Apple should have worked on this.

Answer (score 57):

You can manually add a key in your localization file. You can find the key object by selecting it on storyboard editor. Let's have a look at `Object-ID` in the identity inspector. It's look like `"nwc-b2-19c"`

On your localization update or add translation. For example :

```
"nwc-b2-19c.title" = "Translated title";
```

Comment: think it's the less risky approach

Comment: But some  of the Object-ID are not show in .string file. Because they are not connected. So at that time what can I do?

Comment: is there a way to select it via a name and not just the automatic generated id?

Comment: For a UILabel, its : "YeB-ap-Wkw.text" = "My labels text";

Comment: for me it's not working any more, but 3 years ago it worked...

Answer (score 35):

This one is not for everybody, but it requires no additional tools in the terminal and it's easy for small manual changes. (Do not consider this when you want to automate your process.)

**Step 0: Storyboard language setup**

- Base (with english texts)
- English (localizable strings file does not exist because the base file is english)
- other languages (localizable strings files)

[image: base configuration]

This step is done only once.

Now when I add something to the storyboard I do the following

**Step 1: add the English localizable strings file**

[image: Add English]

just mark the English line item.

This creates a completely new english localizable strings file with all the lines

**Step 2: copy the new line items into the other language files**

and translate them

**Step 3: unmark English, remove the corresponding localizable strings file**

the file was only needed to get the new line items

This is an easy and fast process, everything is done in the storyboard editor

**Edit:**

This process works very well with small storyboards. For example, I have a tabs based project and I have a storyboard for each tab.

Search for "storyboard reference" to find tutorials.

Good example: [Storyboard reference in Xcode, where should we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772145/storyboard-reference-in-xcode-where-should-we-use-it)

So each small storyboard only has a few strings to localize.

Comment: great! Did you also find an idea on how to remove deleted elements?

Comment: @Tobe If you split your storyboard as I suggest above, it is really easy to spot the strings that are not used any more.

Answer (score 15):

Finally, my solution was (rudimentary but effective) copy the previous translations and paste them in the a new file created by unchecking and checking the Localization language box.

This would be useful in some cases like mine when you have to change only one or two texts.

Comment: Would this preserve the id's and such all the time? I did one test and it seemed to work, but it could be a disaster if the id's changed.

Comment: I think so, I've done this a lot of times without any problem.

Comment: IDs are assigned when you dropped the UI elements. They are independent of localisation as they are assigned by storyboard. So there will be no effect on IDs.

Comment: Thanks iBug for the explanation =)

Answer (score 14):

I think the best way is by using built-in export/import Localizations:

1. In Project Navigator choose you project folder
2. Choose Editor > Export For Localization,
3. All translations left on their places and XCode add missed strings automatically.
   Additionally, before import, you can edit .xliff in XLIFF Editor (for example, online -  http://xliff.brightec.co.uk) and then you don't need to do this in XCode.
4. then Editor > Import Localizations and choose saved .xliff file.

P.S. If you don't want to edit in XLIFF Editor and have skipped step 3, XCode can didn't save new strings. In this case open .xliff in XLIFF Editor, re-save without changes and import new file.

Comment: +1 Easy and proper way to work with Localization. Moreover it's preferred way be [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html)

Comment: Using Xcode 7.3.1, in an already localized sample project, I changed a label (from "a text" to "a basic text") and I added a new label. I exported for localization, touched the .xliff file (with no change) and imported it again. In the Main.strings file, the comment line for the changed label has been updated `/* Class = "UILabel"; text = "a basic text"; ObjectID = "HFW-aN-MTb"; */`, but the new label is NOT created in the Main.strings file.  Then I edited the .xliff file to add a translation for the new label. I imported it again. The new label is now inserted in the Main.strings file.

Comment: +1 but there is a bug I've discovered. When adding new elements they are not in an exported file (like duthen is saying). But when I do an export right after (with no changes to storyboard) all added elements are, surprisingly, included. So do an export twice. The second one will include all new elements. Thanks Apple!

Answer (score 7):

When you click in your storyboard, Main.storyboard for example... On right side you can see the localization menu (see atached image). If you uncheck and check again a lenguage, the file will be generated again. So I usually copy the content, I generate the file again and then I paste the content that I copied and already been translated.

This is the way that I use to update the dictionary.

[image]

Comment: With Xcode 10 if you use git it highlights the differences!

Comment: Yes, It is possible... now my file is bigger than in this date and I merge it with repository version after generate it again.

Answer (score 6):

I got a huge storyboard with a lot of strings there. Two languages base english and another arabic. The task was to add some fields and labels to storyboard and add localization for them without any scripts and NSLocalizableStrings.

For me helped next:

*First*: Ensure, you have git to prevent unexpectable changes.

1. Go to target screen in xcode and press `Editor` -> `Export For Localization...`. Save the **ar.xliff** file somewhere.
2. Download [XLIFF Edtior](https://itunes.apple.com/lv/app/xlifftool/id1074282695?mt=12).
3. Open ar.xliff file and make changes.
4. Import this file in xcode. Done! You have updated storyboard strings file.

Comment: For this to work, first select the project or target in the Xcode project editor.

Answer (score 4):

There is <s>an app</s> a command line tool from Apple named [AppleGlot](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=localization) that supports incremental localisation. I haven't tried it yet, but it looks exactly like the tool you searched for (some time ago).

Comment: The `appleglot` tool is working with final application bundles. It is a completely different approach for translation applications.

Comment: Anything wrong with a "different approach", or what causes the downvote?

Comment: Need to search AppleGlot in that link now.

Answer (score 4):

Here is [a script](https://gist.github.com/yoichitgy/29bdd71c3556c2055cc0) to extract strings from storyboards and xibs, and merge them with existing translations.

To run the script automatically when you build a project, put the script into your project root directory, and add a **Run Script** phase with the following line to a target build phases in your project settings.

```
./mergegenstrings.py PathToSourceDir
```

Or you can run the script on Terminal manually when you want to.

The script runs `ibtool` as Tha Leang answered. It also runs `genstrings` to extract and merge strings marked with `NSLocalizedString` in your source code. The script is based on [a script in this post](http://www.stevestreeting.com/2010/05/18/os-x-localisation-incremental-genstrings-and-utf-8-files/), which merges strings after running `genstrings`.

Comment: can you provide more information on how to use this?

Comment: I added a comment to the gist. Hope it helps. https://gist.github.com/yoichitgy/29bdd71c3556c2055cc0

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly for me. If someone has problems with permissions this could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850936/what-permissions-are-required-for-run-script-during-a-build-phase

Comment: This script works fine for storyboard Main.strings files, but seems to be overwriting my Localizable.strings translations in Xcode 7.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest and very less risky approach is, just copy the Object ID from the storyboard and add a new key for the key in the localized file as below example:

**1:** Copy object id as below from storyboard for the component:

[image]

**2:** Add new key in localised file like below:

```
"DjF-dn-0ay.text" = "Borrar datos y restablecer";
```

**Note:** This is very less risky approach if you want to update only few component otherwise you can recreate localised file for the storyboard.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!!!!. I have a question to ask, In my projects, I have not created an outlet for some of the labels, buttons... If I use objectID for those buttons and labels is it enough?

Answer (score 3):

Xlifftool is available as a Mac app and works well.  It shows all the translatable strings and objects from info.plist, localizable strings, and the storyboard.

Get it here for the mac: https://itunes.apple.com/lv/app/xlifftool/id1074282695?mt=12

Step 1: in Xcode, select your project folder in the project navigator.  Then select Editor/Export for Localization...

Your translatable strings will be included in an xliff file under the language you selected for localization in Xcode.

Step 2: Open that file with xlifftool and translate or update your translations there were done previously.

Step 3: Then upload back into your project with Editor/Import Localizations...

Comment: Another alternative for macOS is [Loca Studio](https://www.cunningo.com/locastudio/index.html). Similar to Xlifftool, the app can open the result of the Xcode action Editor -> Export for Localisation. It has some more advanced filtering and search features, and also automatic QA checks. (full disclosure: I am the lead developer).

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**
Xcode can “reload” the file by converting the file to either an `[Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Storyboard]` file type or a `[Localizable Strings]` file type.

Select your base storyboard file from the *Project Navigator*
Find the *Localization* section in the *File Inspector*.
If your file is currently a `[Localizable Strings]`, change it to `[Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Storyboard]` or vice-versa.
Xcode should have converted your storyboard to the current version, while preserving your old localization efforts. Here you can change the file back to the original file type if you would like.

**Option 2**
Use `ibtool` to extract the strings in your storyboard.

Open the Terminal application
Locate your `Base.lproj` directory
Use this line to extract the strings:

```sh
ibtool MainStoryboard.storyboard --generate-strings-file file_name.strings
```

After ibtool extracts the strings to `file_name.strings`, you can copy and paste it to your original `.strings` file.

Answer (score 0):

This is my easy way to update new text from storyboard or xib to localization string

1- use this script http://tredje.se/dev/trouble/?x=entry:entry150917-204052

2- **select your localization string** that you want to update and switch your language string from "Localization string" to "interface builder storyboard"

3- switch it back :)

**Done.**

[image]

Comment: It does change the file to Interface Builder Storyboard but than again after 1 or 2 seconds revert it back to Localizable Strings and no addition to Localizable Strings for new view text

Comment: @MujahidLatif I'm using this Pod right now, it's really useful to me and it's can update storyboard localizations and Localization.String as will 

https://github.com/Flinesoft/BartyCrouch

Answer (score 0):

Add a new language to localise. One that you do not need.

It will produce say Indonesian.strings for example which will contain all the storyboard buttons-names etc which you need, copy and paste all of them into all the other language.string files you have.