# Xcode 5 - Localization xib/nib Update issue

Tags: ios, iphone, localization, xcode5

I am working on project which is `Localized` in many Languages.

`Localization` done perfectly but issue is when i am updating xib, the update not reflect to other language .xib's

Example:

i have changed Label text of ViewController.xib(Base) but change not done on other xib like ViewController.xib(French) and ViewController.xib(German).

- To solve this i tried `Use Base Internationalization` and in my localization `Base` included but this also not solved my problem.

Comment: do you have strings file for other language and folders too

Comment: yes, i have all string files and it work perfect but problem is after localizing xib if i do update it not effects other localized xib

Comment: Please check here http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/localization-tutorial-for-ios and see there might be simple mistake

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094259/is-it-possible-to-update-a-localized-storyboards-strings