# Swift: Localization in Storyboard - Labels not added to Main.strings?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization, localizable.strings

When I try to localize my app and I create a new Main.strings file for the target language, everything I have created in interface builder (labels, buttons, ...) is added to the new Main.strings files (base and language versions) and I can localize the text accordingly.

But when I later add a label or a button to a ViewController in interface builder, it is not automatically added to the Main.strings files for the base and language version.

So, how can I find out what the ObjectID for the button/label is so that I can add it to the strings files?

Or is there another way to force Xcode to add newly added labels and buttons to those files automatically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to update a localized storyboard's strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094259/is-it-possible-to-update-a-localized-storyboards-strings)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

After selecting `UILabel` from storyboard, You can find object id of `UILabel` in right panel:

[image]

Then you can set text of label as below in your `Main.string` file:

```
"sxl-NO-5WX.text" = "Phone";
```

Comment: Was about to give the exact same answer. Took me a day to find this out back then :D

Comment: Is there any way to add them automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Dhaval Bhimani's answer is the easiest solution for localizing a small number of newly added view components. If you want to regenerate all the localizations for a storyboard, select the Main.storyboard-> deselect the localization check boxes for all the languages. check the 'Delete localized resource files from disk' check box
[image]
now make sure your newly added labels and buttons are there and localize again by selecting languages. Just in case backup your string files before that

Answer (score 1):

Use `ObjectID.text` for `UILabel`

Use `ObjectID.normalTitle` for `UIButton`

**Example:**

```
/* Object ID of UILabel */
"GWb-TZ-iGk.text" = "I am label";

/* Object ID of UIButton */
"H6f-pG-K8Z.normalTitle" = "I am button";
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy XIB and Storyboard Localization - Very efficient and simple method

This repository serves as an example on how to localize some UIKit controls:

UILabel,
UIButton,
UITextField placeholder,
UISegmentedControl,
UIBarItem for tab bar items and navigation bar items,
UINavigationItem,
Review Localizable.swift to check it.

https://github.com/emenegro/xib-localization

[image: English]

[image: Spanish]

Comment: Add some code otherwise this can be share in comment also.

Comment: Code is in the repository mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use ibtool to extract the strings in your storyboard.

Open the Terminal application
Locate your Base.lproj directory
Use this line to extract the strings:

ibtool MainStoryboard.storyboard --generate-strings-file file_name.strings

After ibtool extracts the strings to file_name.strings, you can copy and paste it to your original .strings file

(Originally appread here [Is it possible to update a localized storyboard's strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094259/is-it-possible-to-update-a-localized-storyboards-strings))