# How can I add objects id to a localized Storyboard in XCode 9?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I've started an iOS project in XCode 9 and had all the texts and titles in English. When I localized the storyboard magically it creates a Strings file with all the object ids for the UI elements for the language spanish with  and the text I should replace for that language.

Something like this: 
"zxERt-qWop.title"="Texto en espanol"

I noticed when I add an element, let say a label to the storyboard, it doesn't add the objectID automatically which means I would have to write it manually.

Is there an option to add all new objects id to the storyboard string file as is done when you do the localization setup?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to update a localized storyboard's strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094259/is-it-possible-to-update-a-localized-storyboards-strings)

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is. You can do it manually which is not the best thing in the world. The better option in my opinion is to do it with [BartyCrouch](https://github.com/Flinesoft/BartyCrouch/)