# Jenkins building Xcode - getting build error "permission denied"

Tags: ios, xcode, build, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm trying to get a phonegap project building on our Jenkins build server and I'm getting a permission denied error. Keep in mind, this is my first experience with Mac OS X.

The build output in Jenkins is telling me this:

```
    /bin/sh -c \"/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/myMobile\ -\ iOS/workspace/build/TDE.build/Release-iphoneos/TDE.build/Script-304B58A110DAC018002A0835.sh\"
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/myMobile - iOS/workspace/build/TDE.build/Release-iphoneos/TDE.build/Script-304B58A110DAC018002A0835.sh: line 2: cordova/lib/copy-www-build-step.sh: Permission denied

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution Copy\ www\ directory build/TDE.build/Release-iphoneos/TDE.build/Script-304B58A110DAC018002A0835.sh
(1 failure)
Build step 'XCode' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Googling this, I found a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850936/what-permissions-are-required-for-run-script-during-a-build-phase) saying to run the chmod 755 command on this .sh file, but that still didn't fix anything. What else should I be doing to get this file to be able to execute/copy or whatever it's doing?

Edit: Is my actual permission issue for this file:

```
line 2: cordova/lib/copy-www-build-step.sh: Permission denied
```

Or is it the Script-.... file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added permissions on the ...copy-www-build-step.sh file and that fixed THIS build error. On to the next...

In order for these permissions to stay even after doing a full-checkout from SVN via Jenkins, find the copy-www-build-step in your source control. View the properties for the file, and add svn:executable.

This fixes it so you don't have to keep updating the permissions if you do a full checkout for every build.

Answer (score -1):

I get the answer... I have to change the file permissions.. sudo chmod 777 copy-www-build-step.sh

just move to the platforms/ios/cordova/lib and execute the above command.