# Git: Count commits since tag

Tags: git

I am trying to count the number of commits since a tag was made.

I have tried using `git rev-list` but it seems to return the same results no matter what I try.  This is what I have tried:

```
$ git rev-list 1.7Start^..HEAD | wc -l
13902
$ git rev-list HEAD | wc -l
13902
```

Trying to count how many commits since the 1.7Start tag was created. I'm currently on `master` hence using `HEAD` but using `git rev-list master | wc -l` gives me the same.

There hasn't been 13000+ commits since 1.7

Should `git rev-list master` show me every commit in master and hence yield a larger number than `1.7Start^..master` which should just give me the difference?

Comment: That suggests to me that there's no history in common between `1.7Start^` and `HEAD`.  To test if that's the case, see what `git merge-base 1.7Start^ HEAD` produces - my guess is an error indicating that there's no commit in common.

Comment: no error, and no return value

Comment: Right, that indicates that there is no history in common, which is surprising.  How was this tag generated?

Comment: Or, to be more precise, how is it that `1.7Start` has a different root commit from `HEAD`?

Comment: ahh I see what has happened now.  At around that same we time migrated from svn to git. The 1.7 branch was already created in svn and so the commits in the 1.7 branch differ from master because it never branched from there.  I found the same commit in master and created a new tag.  Works fine now.

Comment: git rev-list --count HEAD ^<your tag> See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657295/count-the-number-of-commits-on-a-git-branch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The results that you're getting suggest that there is no history in common between `1.7Start^` and `HEAD`, so `1.7Start` and `HEAD` must have different root commits.  (The syntax `a..b` when passed to `git rev-list` just means "every commit in `b` which isn't in `a`.)

In the comments above, the questioner indicated that this arose because the repository was migrated from Subversion, and `master` is entirely distinct from the imported branch that `1.7Start` points to.

Answer (score 4):

If you only care about the **last tag**, as is typical, `git describe` will tell you **what the last tag is and how many commits were made in the current branch since it**. For example, in the output below, the last tag was 0.1.9 and 67 commits were made in the current branch since it.

```
$ git describe --tags

0.1.9-67-gff9fd30
```

For verification, you can see the full list of commits using the command below.

```
$ git log --oneline $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)..
```

If you pipe its output to `wc -l`, the same count should be returned. Note that `!!` is the previous command in Bash.

```
$ !! | wc -l

67
```

Comment: Combining this with a build phase bash scripts for Xcode suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24750392/84682 - the build number can automatically be updated to reflect the number of Git commits since last release (most recent tagged). Perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Git has git rev-list --count which does this faster then wc-l.

There is also the git rev-list --use-bitmap-index --count in later versions of git, which is an optimization of --count.

rev-list needs a commit, so an example, to find all the commits in your repo for your current branch.

```
git rev-list --count HEAD
```