# Is there a way to see a count of all contributions made to Github by me?

Tags: github

The calendar shows contributions made in the last year. Is there a way to see a similar count but without a start date restriction ?

Comment: Can you just use the git command line?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657295/count-the-number-of-commits-on-a-git-branch or http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/01/22/count-your-commits.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Github API** to retrieve statistics on your repositories and a few lines of code to generate a global count.

**Note:** There is a pretty low limit in terms of requests for public access. I advise you to generate a token (`Settings > Developper settings > Personal access tokens`) with `Access commit status` and `Read all user profile data` rights.

Here is a small bash script using `curl` and `jq`. You just have to change your user name. You can also uncomment the AUTH line and set your generated token to avoid hitting the limit of queries:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Parameters
USER=jyvet
#AUTH="-u $USER:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

GAPI="https://api.github.com"
REPOS=$(curl $AUTH -s $GAPI/users/$USER/repos | jq -c -r '.[].name')

COMMITS=0
ADDITIONS=0
DELETIONS=0

# Iterate over all the repositories owned by the user
for r in $REPOS; do
    STATS=$(curl $AUTH -s "$GAPI/repos/$USER/$r/stats/contributors" |
            jq ".[] | select(.author.login == \"$USER\")" 2> /dev/null)

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        tmp=$(echo -n "$STATS" | jq '.total' 2> /dev/null)
        COMMITS=$(( COMMITS + tmp ))

        tmp=$(echo -n "$STATS" | jq '[.weeks[].a] | add' 2> /dev/null)
        ADDITIONS=$(( ADDITIONS + tmp ))

        tmp=$(echo -n "$STATS" | jq '[.weeks[].d] | add' 2> /dev/null)
        DELETIONS=$(( DELETIONS + tmp ))
    fi
done

echo "Commits: $COMMITS, Additions: $ADDITIONS, Deletions: $DELETIONS"
```

Result:

```
> Commits: 193, Additions: 20403, Deletions: 2687
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to see a similar count but without a start date restriction ?

No, but I built [**`git-stats`**](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/git-stats)–a tool to track your local commits and show graphs like GitHub does.

> [image]
>
> An example with my graphs.