# Count number of commits between tag creation and current HEAD commit across all branches in git

Tags: git

From [Count the number of commits on a Git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657295/count-the-number-of-commits-on-a-git-branch) I have learned, how to get the Number of commits on a single branch since my Tag was created. My Question now is how I can get the absolute difference since the Tag was created across all Branches in my Repository?

For Example I have my branch master, branches feature/somefeature1, feature/somefeature2, release/somerelease, and my Tag refs/tags/sometag1.

where I want to sum up all commits since refs/tags/sometag1 was created.

Comment: What happens if the tag does not appear in the history of a certain branch, e.g. some branch split from `master` before the tag got created?

Comment: Off the top of my head, you could use `git branch --contains <tag>` to identify all branches having this tag, then use your current solution to get the count.  This could be done from a script (@VonC are you reading this?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking about local branches you can use `rev-list` to do exactly the same count:

```
git rev-list --count --branches ^refs/tags/sometag1
```

All the same options apply as in the linked question, so you can also pass things like `--no-merges` if required.

Note that this interprets "since" in a topological or ancestry sense so if you have an old branch that was never merged, those unmerged commits would count towards the total.

For a strictly commit date based solution you could do something like:

```
git rev-list --count --branches --since="$(git show -s --format=%ct refs/tags/sometag1^{})"
```