# How to get the exact number of commits on a repo?

Tags: git

I'm trying to get the total number of commits on a git repository, but the numbers seem wrong.

My first thought was to use:

```
git log --pretty=oneline | wc -l
```

Doing some research, I found a method that seems more appropriate for the task:

```
git rev-list --all --count
```

The thing is, even though they seem to accomplish the same thing, I'm getting different results. On a sample repository, the `log` command returns 1039 commits, whilst `rev-list` returns 1044 commits.

Why am I getting different results?

Comment: It's `--pretty=oneline`, not *"online"*. `git log` displays only the commits that are accessible from the starting point you provide it (or from the current branch if no reference is provided). It doesn't show the branches that were not merged. It is not the tool you need.

Comment: git rev-list HEAD --count. -all will take all the refs from refs/ folder which would be all the remote and local branch commits. You would only want commits from current branch to count, hence, the difference in count.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count the number of commits on a Git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657295/count-the-number-of-commits-on-a-git-branch)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the Git commit count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677436/how-do-i-get-the-git-commit-count)

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution:

```
> git rev-list --count HEAD
```

#### Explanation:

The above command allows you to count the number of commits for the branch you are on.

- Ref: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list