# AGVTool new-version and what-version do not correspond

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, agvtool

When I do:

```
agvtool new-version -all 99
```

It updates my Info.plist file. However, if I do this:

```
agvtool what-version
```

or

```
agvtool next-version
```

I get this error:

```
There does not seem to be a CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION key set for this project.
Add this key to your target's expert build settings.
```

Why does this not correspond. Do I have to use the plist command line tool in order to retrieve the current version of my app. Curiously `agvtool what-marketing-version` works fine. Ironically agvtool does not seem to have a version itself ;-)

Comment: I've had no end of problems using `agvtool`. I use `Plistbuddy` instead, with great success.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258344/xcode-better-way-of-incrementing-build-number

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This link worked for me [Technical Q&A QA1827 Automating Version and Build Numbers Using agvtool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1827/_index.html)

From the link is the following. This help resolve the issue when I started using the agvtool.

1. Enable agvtool.

Navigate to the Build Settings pane of your target, then update it for all your build configurations.

Set Current Project Version to a value of your choosing. I set my to 1

Set Versioning System to Apple Generic.

By default, Xcode does not use any versioning system. Setting Versioning System to Apple Generic ensures that Xcode will include all agvtool-generated version information in your project.

2. Set up your version and build numbers.

agvtool searches your application’s Info.plist for your version and build numbers. It updates them if they exist and does nothing, otherwise. Make sure that the CFBundleVersion (Bundle version) and CFBundleShortVersionString (Bundle versions string, short) keys exist in your Info.plist

Comment: Just don't go down this path if you expect to use agvtool as part of a Run Script build phase to automatically increment build numbers on every build or archive. This will silently cancel the build because agvtool alters the project file. Hope I saved someone 10 minutes there.

Comment: @AdamEberbach you just saved me possibly HOURS AND HOURS. thank you.