# Bump build number without using `CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION`

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, agvtool

Since [I can't bump my build number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737325/agvtool-new-version-and-what-version-do-not-correspond) using agvtool I am wondering if there is a quick way to bump the build number in my project using the command line.

I would rather not have to parse the plist's XML if this is possible.

Comment: Yes, use the script in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258344/xcode-better-way-of-incrementing-build-number

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set the version of all the targets for your Xcode build in the command prompt using "$ agvtool new-version -all x.x.x".  Hope this helps!