# Showing App's Build Date

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, build

I am able to display the build date for my app in the simulator, but whenever I archive the app, and upload it to TestFlight, and then install it on a device, the build date doesn't show.

Here is what I'm doing to display the build date.

First, I added **CFBuildDate** as a string to myproject-info.plist

Next, I added the following script to Edit Scheme -> Build -> Pre-Actions -> Run Script Action :

```
infoplist="$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$INFOPLIST_PATH"
builddate=`date`
if [[ -n "$builddate" ]]; then
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :CFBuildDate $builddate" ${infoplist}
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBuildDate $builddate" ${infoplist}
fi
```

Finally, used the following code to get the build date from the plist file :

```
NSString *build_date = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBuildDate"];
```

This displays the build date in simulator (though occasionally it doesn't), but when deploying the app through TestFlight, the build date never displays. Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try running the script as a *build step* so it's run all the time, regardless of the type of build you are producing.

Comment: Why do you need the build date?

Comment: @trojanfoe - So I added the same script as a new Run Script in Build Phases. Will try that get back to you with the results.

Comment: @SimonH - I know it's not that important, but some of the testers in my company have requested that to keep track of the builds.

Comment: Surely updating the build/version number would be better +I know this works :)

Comment: Agreed.  See this excellent SO question of mine :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258344/xcode-better-way-of-incrementing-build-number

Comment: @trojanfoe Running script in build phases worked ! Thanks so much. If you can post your solution as the answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: I don't know how to use Objective-C to handle this. However, I successfully did this with Swift. You can manually expose my Swift solution to Objective-C by adding an @objc prefix towards my method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76731173/4162914 Note that the essense is to verify the codesign timestamp, hence the requirements that your app must be propertly signed by Apple using your Developer ID Application certificate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try running the script as a *build phase* step, rather than a scheme pre-action step, so it's run all the time, regardless of the type of build you are producing.

Answer (score 28):

You might consider using the built-in `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` macros which will return a string representation of the date and time the app was built.  Perhaps they will be of more help to you:

```
NSString *dateStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:__DATE__];
NSString *timeStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:__TIME__];
```

Comment: +1 Haven't tried that, but looks like an elegant solution. Thanks !

Comment: That's a good solution, however the date/time aren't within the `Info.plist` file, and therefore are not externally visible.

Comment: What is 'externally visible'?  It will be accessible to the build_date variable.

Comment: Keep in mind that the `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` constants are in the developer machine's local time. There's no constant that tells you what that is.

Comment: in order for this to be build date and time for whole project I added a pre build script line to touch file with this code otherwise the timestamp is when that file was last modified, not timestamp of build

Comment: This does not work well - the date will *only* be updated when the source file with this code needs to be recompiled. So, if you forget to clean your project before building and also have not made any changes to this file, you will end up getting the last modification date of that file, not of your latest build process.

Answer (score 12):

To get build date with format 'yyMMddHHmm' you could try this:

```
+ (NSString *)GetBuildDate {
    NSString *buildDate;

    // Get build date and time, format to 'yyMMddHHmm'
    NSString *dateStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:__DATE__], [NSString stringWithUTF8String:__TIME__]];

    // Convert to date
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"LLL d yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];

    // Set output format and convert to string
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyMMddHHmm"];
    buildDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];

    [dateFormat release];

    return buildDate;
}
```

Comment: Nice :) but dont forget to set the locale, or it will not work everywhere.    [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];

Comment: This does not work well - the date will *only* be updated when the source file with this code needs to be recompiled. So, if you forget to clean your project before building and also have not made any changes to this file, you will end up getting the last modification date of that file, not of your latest build process.

Answer (score 6):

If you redefine `__DATE__` and `__TIME__`  it will make the time update every time you build your app. you won´t need to clean or archive to update the time, just need run the project.

```
  #define DATE [NSString stringWithUTF8String:__DATE__]
  #define TIME [NSString stringWithUTF8String:__TIME__]


- (NSString *)getBuildDate {
    NSString *buildDate;

    // Get build date and time, format to 'yyMMddHHmm'
    NSString *dateStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", DATE , TIME ];

    // Convert to date
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"LLL d yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
    NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
    [dateFormat setLocale:usLocale];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];

    // Set output format and convert to string
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy-HH:mm"];
    buildDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];

    return buildDate;
}
```

Comment: This does not work well - the date will *only* be updated when the source file with this code needs to be recompiled. So, if you forget to clean your project before building and also have not made any changes to this file, you will end up getting the last modification date of that file, not of your latest build process.

Answer (score 6):

## Swift3

```
static var buildDate: Date? {
    guard let infoPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Info.plist", ofType: nil) else {
        return nil
    }
    guard let infoAttr = try? FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: infoPath) else {
        return nil
    }
    let key = FileAttributeKey(rawValue: "NSFileCreationDate")
    guard let infoDate = infoAttr[key] as? Date else {
        return nil
    }
    return infoDate
}

static var prettyBuildDate: String {
    guard let date = buildDate else {
        return "Unknown"
    }
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    return formatter.string(from: date)
}
```

Comment: This is not giving a consistent result with `__DATE__` since when you update your app info.plist will remain the same while `__DATE__` gets proper updated by the time of the update.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS, I use this code, which fetches the build date from the app's Info.plist content. Might also work on iOS, I haven't checked:

```
+ (NSDate *)buildDate {
    static NSDate *result = nil;
    if (result == nil) { 
        NSDictionary *infoDictionary = NSBundle.mainBundle.infoDictionary;
        NSString *s = [infoDictionary valueForKey:@"BuildDateString"];
        NSISO8601DateFormatter *formatter = [[NSISO8601DateFormatter alloc] init];
        NSDate *d = [formatter dateFromString:s];
        result = d;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Swift5

```
let compileDate = String(Date())
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "MMM-dd-yyyy"
let usLocale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
df.locale = usLocale
let aDate: Date? = df.date(from: compileDate)
```

Comment: `Date()` returns the date of runtime, not compiled time