# How to get iOS APP archive date using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, macos

I have a requirement in my application that, i need to show .ipa file creation date using swift.

Can anybody tell me how to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26812598/get-build-date-and-time-in-swift

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the url of your app using Bundle property [executableURL](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/bundle/1410470-executableurl) and use url method [resourceValues](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/url/1780058-resourcevalues) to get the bundle creation date:

```
if let executableURL = Bundle.main.executableURL,
    let creation = (try? executableURL.resourceValues(forKeys: [.creationDateKey]))?.creationDate {
    print(creation)
}
```