# Is there any way to get the date on which the application was compiled? React Native App

Tags: android, ios, react-native, build

I need to pass the date of the day which the application was compiled. I mean, if tomorrow I compile and launch version 3.4 of my app, I need to save it into a variable local. I obviously could do it by saving the date manually before compile, but I need to save it in another way to avoid to forget to change the local variable before compile it.

My application is powered by React-Native. So I was searching a library to do it with but i had no luck.

Comment: For iOS (Swift/Objective C), check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26812598/get-build-date-and-time-in-swift

Comment: I would do it with a script, with the sed command. Before build your app, run the script and everything is fine. There has to be some way to launch a custom scipt from xCode or android studio

Comment: Nice idea, I like it, I have been searching and nothing found but this could be a great alternative