# Auto increment build number xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am trying to implement the answer here:

[Better way of incrementing build number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258344/xcode-better-way-of-incrementing-build-number)

but cannot get it to work properly. It fails with error 2 saying "No build number in plist"

But if I put a build number in my plist, the script clears it on the next build, then the same thing happens all over again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's how I increment build numbers:

In the Target > Summary tab, set the initial build #
[image]

Then use this script to increment the build number:

```
#!/bin/bash
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
buildNumber=$(printf "%04d" $buildNumber)
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
```

or if you want build numbers in hex:

```
#!/bin/bash
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
buildNumber=$((0x$buildNumber))
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
buildNumber=$(printf "%04X" $buildNumber)
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
```

Comment: Thanks..maybe that was the problem I initially set build to 1.1.0.0 as I thought that was how build versions were formatted, doing it without decimals does seem to work but now build is simply single digit. How can I make it a 4 digit build number format?

Comment: @ourmanflint I think the snippets above should give you a four digit build number (`%04d` and `%04X`) or do you mean a four digit number like 1.1.0.0?  Depends on whether you want to increment build numbers `CFBundleVersion`, version numbers `CFBundleShortVersionString`, or both.

Comment: That buildNumber=$((0x$buildNumber)) line should be removed as it converts in hex a decimal number.

Comment: this does not work for me the build numbers always range between 0001 - 006

Answer (score 3):

My solution is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
buildNumber=$(echo $buildNumber | sed 's/0*//')
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
buildNumber=$(printf "%04d" $buildNumber)
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
```

Using sed to remove leading zeroes, incrementing the value and printing it back in the plist file using a four-digit-zero-padded number.

Comment: Take that back... after `000A`, it rolls back to `0001`!!

Comment: There is no 000A since it only prints number. I can assure you this works flawlessly since I am now at build number 2923 and I started from 0. After 0009 it goes to 0010. After 9999 it goes to 10000. Double check you are *actually* using my code.

Comment: I changed %04d to %04x

Comment: Then you should tell bash that buildNumber is an hex number. You should add `buildNumber=$((0x$buildNumber))` before incrementing it (line 3).

Comment: "You last voted on this answer 15 hours ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited". sorry

Answer (score 0):

And if you use Jenkins you can use the Jenkins build number

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $BUILD_NUMBER" "$INFOPLIST_FILE";
```

Comment: Tried this but it does not work. Am I missing something? The build number in plist is always 1, build number in jenkins is 60

Comment: Besides the path to your Plist that could be wrong, I can only imagine that maybe the original Plist needs any dummy `CFBundleVersion` entry so that PlistBuddy can find and replace it.