# Difference between NIB from Xcode and App Store

Tags: ios, xcode

we got a business app in app store and since last update the main shaped button on the main view isn't working. The User can't touch up the button. 
Now, it doesn't work only in app store app. When I deploy the app (same code, same version) directly from Xcode to same device, it works. So, why?
With iExplorer I've export both folder an compared it. What I could see is, that the .nib files are different. In that special case, the main view with the shaped button, also the file size is diffrent. Xcode Version has a file size of 10814 Bytes, the App Store Version only 10804. Can someone explain it to me?

thanks

Comment: Are you sure this isn't an earlier version of the app you submitted?  If you use an incremental build number (see link) then you will know for sure that the app version is different: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258344/xcode-better-way-of-incrementing-build-number

Comment: I didn't change code after upload to app store. So why I should have different versions?

Comment: You shouldn't; but you didn't say you hadn't change the code in your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right. But it also doesn't make sense to compare two different version of the app. I did submit the app to app store. After that I didn't change any code or version number. But the app is not working the same way on iDevices (iPhone4, iPhone4S, IPad2, iPhone5) when deployt from xcode or app store.

Comment: That is worrying.  Do you know what Apple does to an .app before it gets distributed on the app store?  I understand it gets encrypted and some meta data files are added to the bundle.  Is that correct?

Comment: well, that's my question. What happens to all the files? I knew that the app is signed, but I didn't know all files were changed.

Comment: I wouldn't expect the nib file to change at all.