# How to auto increment build number in Xcode

Tags: xcode, build, xcode4

I found many solutions and scripts on this site, but the easiest solution to increase the build number in Xcode is:

Go to Build Phases in your TARGETS section and add Run Script Build Phase:

[image: Auto increment build numbers in xcode]

Change Shell to /bin/bash and insert the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
```

Have fun! :)

[I found this tutorial on Cocoa Factory](http://cocoafactory.com/blog/2013/03/18/auto-incrementing-xcode-build-numbers/)

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm for me. For those who don't know how to add the script, the **Add Run Script Build Phase** is located at Editor > Add Build Phase.

Comment: This should be posted as a question, with the solution posted as an answer below.

Comment: Actually this question is a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258344/xcode-better-way-of-incrementing-build-number