# How to auto increment the build number in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, build, xcode5

I was wondering if Xcode 5 is providing a setting to automatically count up the Build number found under General in the Identity section of the project navigator.

But afaik you still have to do it with scripting, using PlistBuddy.

One simple solution is to increase the build number in Xcode 5 is posted below:

Comment: even a shell script will do...

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163396/how-to-auto-increment-build-number-in-xcode

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I've asked it again because a mod closed it and asked me to post it a question.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Go to Editor -> Add Build Phase -> Add Run Script Build Phase

[image: Add Run Script Build Phase]

Go to Build Phases in the project navigator and edit Run Sript.
Change Shell to /bin/bash and paste the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
```

[image: Enter PlistBuddy Script]

Don't forget to change the Build number found under General in the Identity section from 1.0 to 1

Have fun! :)

[I found this tutorial on Cocoa Factory](http://cocoafactory.com/blog/2013/03/18/auto-incrementing-xcode-build-numbers/)

Comment: Poor solution as the build number will increment every time a build is performed, whether a source file has changed or not.  That's not very useful and this solution is better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258344/xcode-better-way-of-incrementing-build-number

Comment: I changed the "$INFOPLIST_FILE" string to "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}".

Then I edited the scheme and put the script in as a "post-action". I made sure to check the "Provide build settings from <App>" and set the shell to /bin/bash.

I put it as a post-action so that I know exactly what build I'm doing. Great for simple apps. I recommend a makefile for automated builds for more serious applications. Happy coding!

Comment: Note that this will fail if your current CFBundleVersion includes a decimal, e.g. "1.0". Shell scripts can only add integers with the raw + operator.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically add this to ever project?

Comment: @trojanfoe this worked fine for me as long as you check the 'run script only when installing checkbox'

Comment: For anyone wondering "[Run script only when installing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913199/xcode-run-script-build-phase-run-script-only-when-installing-option)" will only run the script when you Archive your app for upload.

Comment: I'm trying to get this working in Xcode 6.1 with a Swift project but the Add Run Script Build Phase menu item is disabled. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Nevermind! Could add it via the Build Phases Tab!

Comment: To add the script in Xcode 6.1 you need to go to Your Project > Build Phases Tab and then click the little '+' towards the top left, right below the bar with all the tabs on it. Click "New Run Script Phase"