# How to avoid infinite loop by using git commit number as xcode build number

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I recently use a script to increase my project's build number related to git commits, and i ran into an infinite loop.

I build, then the build number is changed, then i commit because the info.plist is changed, then the build number will be changed next time i build, so i have to commit it again since the info.plist is changed, then you know what is gonna happen.

is there any way to avoid this? or is there a better way to increase the build number automatically?

ps. since i worked the project with others, change the number by hand or bumps it every time i build is quite difficult to maintain the number.

Comment: I use something [similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114376/how-to-auto-increment-the-build-number-in-xcode-5) but instead of incrementing a number, i count the number of commits since the project's start with `git rev-list HEAD --count`.

Comment: See also http://blog.jaredsinclair.com/post/97193356620/the-best-of-all-possible-xcode-automated-build

Comment: @GuillaumeAlgis: i do use `git rev-list HEAD --count`. :(

Comment: The "trick" in the article I linked is to never write the commit count in any file known to git. The count is written at the last minute into Info.plist *in the final build directory* (not your sources dir) just before creating and signing the `.ipa`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/35407266/2998

Comment: There are other ways as well.  As per [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258344/better-way-of-incrementing-build-number), where Xcode was getting upset when the `Info.plist` file was being updated behind its back, the simplest solution was to add the *bump build number* script as a separate Xcode target and make the other targets dependent upon *that* target.  Then the `Info.plist` file has been updated well before Xcode needs to look at it, and that makes it happy.  Last-minute-copying works, for sure, but it's not simplest solution to diagnose when things start going wrong.

Comment: @StephenDarlington Did you mean to self-reference this question?

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes. It's a bad infinite loop joke.

Comment: @StephenDarlington Oh, blimey.  Yeah. OK.

Comment: @GuillaumeAlgis Thanks, this works. but there is another issue: when i try to archive it, the build number seems stick to info.plist. so i change the file again when i need to archive it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah this is a classic issue.  I use a similar technique but I don't relate the build number to the git commits, instead I detect changes to files in the source tree in relation to the modified time of a *version file* (a simple file that holds the version and build number).  If there are changes then I bump the build number.

Here the python script I use.  You should make it a separate target in your Xcode project and then make other targets dependent upon this target.  It will update your `.plist` file(s) with the new version/build number as necessary.  It assumes the source tree is below the location of the *version file*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# Bump build number in Info.plist files if a source file have changed.
#
# usage: bump_buildnum.py buildnum.ver Info.plist [ ... Info.plist ]
#
# andy@trojanfoe.com, 2014.
#

import sys, os, subprocess, re

def read_verfile(name):
    version = None
    build = None
    verfile = open(name, "r")
    for line in verfile:
        match = re.match(r"^version\s+(\S+)", line)
        if match:
            version = match.group(1).rstrip()
        match = re.match(r"^build\s+(\S+)", line)
        if match:
            build = int(match.group(1).rstrip())
    verfile.close()
    return (version, build)

def write_verfile(name, version, build):
    verfile = open(name, "w")
    verfile.write("version {0}\n".format(version))
    verfile.write("build {0}\n".format(build))
    verfile.close()
    return True

def set_plist_version(plistname, version, build):
    if not os.path.exists(plistname):
        print("{0} does not exist".format(plistname))
        return False

    plistbuddy = '/usr/libexec/Plistbuddy'
    if not os.path.exists(plistbuddy):
        print("{0} does not exist".format(plistbuddy))
        return False

    cmdline = [plistbuddy,
        "-c", "Set CFBundleShortVersionString {0}".format(version),
        "-c", "Set CFBundleVersion {0}".format(build),
        plistname]
    if subprocess.call(cmdline) != 0:
        print("Failed to update {0}".format(plistname))
        return False

    print("Updated {0} with v{1} ({2})".format(plistname, version, build))
    return True

def should_bump(vername, dirname):
    verstat = os.stat(vername)
    allnames = []
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dirname):
        for filename in filenames:
            allnames.append(os.path.join(dirname, filename))

    for filename in allnames:
        filestat = os.stat(filename)
        if filestat.st_mtime > verstat.st_mtime:
            print("{0} is newer than {1}".format(filename, vername))
            return True

    return False

def upver(vername):
    (version, build) = read_verfile(vername)
    if version == None or build == None:
        print("Failed to read version/build from {0}".format(vername))
        return False

    # Bump the version number if any files in the same directory as the version file
    # have changed, including sub-directories.
    srcdir = os.path.dirname(vername)
    bump = should_bump(vername, srcdir)

    if bump:
        build += 1
        print("Incremented to build {0}".format(build))
        write_verfile(vername, version, build)
        print("Written {0}".format(vername))
    else:
        print("Staying at build {0}".format(build))

    return (version, build)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if os.environ.has_key('ACTION') and os.environ['ACTION'] == 'clean':
        print("{0}: Not running while cleaning".format(sys.argv[0]))
        sys.exit(0)

    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        print("Usage: {0} buildnum.ver Info.plist [... Info.plist]".format(sys.argv[0]))
        sys.exit(1)
    vername = sys.argv[1]

    (version, build) = upver(vername)
    if version == None or build == None:
        sys.exit(2)

    for i in range(2, len(sys.argv)):
        plistname = sys.argv[i]
        set_plist_version(plistname, version, build)        

    sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach I use is to have a placeholder in the file that contains the version number, and then having the build server replace that placeholder with the correct version number *locally* before creating which the distributable package. The version of info.plist that is in the repository does not get changed; it always has the placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

I made a version of @trojanfoe's answer in pure bash. This assumes a file called `versions` placed in the root project directory.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

beginswith() { case $2 in "$1"*) true;; *) false;; esac; }

shopt -s dotglob

versionModifiedAt=$(date -r versions +%s)
needsUpdate=false

processEntry() {
  if [[ "$1" == "versions" ]]; then return; fi
  if [[ "$1" == ".git" ]];     then return; fi
  if beginswith ".git/" "$1";  then return; fi

  if [ $(date -r "$1" +%s) -gt "$versionModifiedAt" ]; then
    needsUpdate=true
  fi
}

# Top level
for entry in *; do
  processEntry "$entry"
  if [[ $needsUpdate == true ]]; then
    break;
  fi
done

# Nested
if [[ $needsUpdate != true ]]; then
  for entry in **/*; do
    processEntry "$entry"
    if [[ $needsUpdate == true ]]; then
      break;
    fi
  done
fi

if [[ $needsUpdate != true ]]; then
  echo "No update needed"
  exit 0
fi
echo "Updating version and build info"


buildPlist=${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}

# Increment build number
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$buildPlist")
buildNumber=$((0x$buildNumber))
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
buildNumber=$(printf "%04X" $buildNumber)
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$buildPlist"

echo -e "${git_release_version#*v}\n$buildNumber" > versions
```