# How to add build script Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, xcode

So I was trying to follow this SO answer:

[Better way of incrementing build number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258344/xcode-better-way-of-incrementing-build-number)

However when I run the script - it fails with exit code 1. I think thats something to do with the Plist?

Questions:

1. How do I add the script to the path:

   > ${PROJECT_DIR}/tools (sibling to the .xcodeproj directory):
2. Why am I getting an exit code 1 error?

Comment: does the Build Log (which you can expand when it hits the Run Script build phase) give any useful hints?

Comment: All I get is this:Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me.

I used the two scripts from this git hub repo:

https://gist.github.com/sekati/3172554

For the build number - once this number is just to keep track of my builds I added it to the pre-actions of my build scheme like so:

- Edit Scheme
- Expand "Build" section by clicking disclosure triangle
- Select "Pre-actions"
- Add "New Run-Script Action"
- Select "Provide build settings from $YOUR_PROJECT"
- Add an increment script

This increments the build number every time I build / Run the app.

Then for the version number - I wanted this only to increment when I archive. As this is the stage where I release the app to testers or App store and thus, its important to keep an accurate version number.

To do this:

- Edit Scheme
- Expand "Archive" section by clicking disclosure triangle
- Select "Pre-actions"
- Add "New Run-Script Action"
- Select "Provide build settings from $YOUR_PROJECT"
- Add an increment script

Hope this helps others.