# XCode6 GoldMaster submitting build failed with error

Tags: ios, xcode6

When I submit build to AppStore I see errors:

ERROR ITMS-4088: "No software found with apple_id: ***" at SofwareAssets

ERROR ITMS-4238: "Redundant Binary Upload. There already exists a binary upload with build version '3.0' for train '3.0' at SoftwareAssets/PreReleaseSoftwareAsset.

Does anybody know what I should do to fix that?

Comment: I understood the reason for the error ITMS-4088. This is due to the wrong account when you send in the ITC.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Fix your apple id there `*"` is strange, i.e. only use normal characters and then do the following to increase the build:

A more than one binary may be uploaded to iTunesConnect if the the Build number (Select the Target, then Xcode -> General -> Build, see the picture below) is increased by adding `.1`, i.e. if the version is `3.75`, then increase it to: `3.75.1`, but the Version is still `3.75 for the App (also in iTunesConnect). The build number just has to be unique for each binary that is loaded up to iTunesConnect.

[image: Showing where to set the Build Version in XCode]

After a new binary is uploaded and processed (~ 10 min), then you can select the new binary and submit it for review. In the picture below you may see the old and the new binary listed in iTunesConnect in the Build section of the current App version (you click the plus sign). Then the new binary is selected -> `Saved` -> `Submit for Review`. (Sometimes an error comes when submitting, then just try after a few mins or upload a new binary build).

[image: Showing list of binaries in iTunesConnect]

For those inclined to do this automatically with an Xcode script, here is a description of making an automatic script for updating Build numbers [Better way of incrementing build number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258344/better-way-of-incrementing-build-number)

Comment: Thanks, but I do not see anywhere my uploaded builds.

Comment: @MikhailS They take some time in processing before they show up. If you don't see it within 20 min, just upload again.

Comment: I've been waiting an hour.

Comment: @MikhailS - Then upload again. Mark the answer also as it solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks Hannes - this saved my night and spared me from a lot of headache.

Answer (score 28):

For the error ERROR ITMS-4088: "No software found with apple_id: *" at SofwareAssets

Make sure you have the correct itunesconnect account connected with xcode.

- Sign into > https://itunesconnect.apple.com
- Users + Roles
- Add iTunes Connect User

  - specify your developer account email address
  - grant admin or technical access (this allows generation of certs)

Alternatively - you can simply add in the production iTunes Connect login details in xcode.

- Xcode / preferences(cmd + ,)
- Accounts -> add iTunes Connect apple id.
- Archive -> choose the corresponding iTunes Connect account to submit.

[image]

Currently, the iTunes Connect user account is limited to one commercial entity. 
Whereas the Apple developer account can be granted access to multiple organisations.
To get around this, use a different email address or alias to successfully add your iTunes Connect User.

Comment: You can add each iTunesConnect account to Xcode via Xcode > Preferences > Account. Then select the appropriate account when you upload your app.

Comment: Should that iTunes Connect email address also be in the developer program?

Comment: Hi Jan, ideally - add your developer account into itunesconnect. I've updated answer to reflect this.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer. In my case the issue was misleading because my developer account had access (as developer) to the iTunes account but it was not registered as an iTunes user for that account as the same email was used for another iTunes account. So I could see the right developer profile but getting the same error message. I fixed it as suggested by adding the extra iTunes account.

Comment: You could also sign into the Application loader with the iTunesConnect Email.. Then in Xcode you just need to export a ipa file. Maybe thats easier..

Comment: This is the correct answer, the error seems to be caused by a mismatch between iTunes developer account and iTunes Connect account.. Unfortunately, unlike developer account, the same Apple Id cannot be used on several iTunes Connect account.

So, if like me, you associated your Apple Id as a developer account to several developer organizations, and you try to submit a build to iTunes Connect, use Apple Application Loader

Comment: Yes, and after you add the iTunes Connect agent apple ID to Xcode, you need to make sure you choose it during the submission process.  Click on the pop-up "account" menu to make sure it doesn't auto-choose an apple ID that is linked only as a Developer.

Answer (score 10):

This can also be caused by not being the **agent.** you can't submit as just an admin for itunesconnect. XCode6 does not have a separate login for itunesconnect like previous versions, so it uses your standard account. Go to Xcode>Preferences>Accounts and sign in with the itunesconnect agent account. Then you will be get rid of the Error ITMS-4088

Comment: Thanks! Signing into Xcode's accounts as the agent did the trick.

Comment: So basically, the developer that build and submit the app to the store has to signin in XCode has the agent?

Comment: Yes. You had to in older version of Xcode as well, but it asked when you tried to submit. All account logins are now int he preference section under accounts, including the one you need to use for itunesconnect.

Answer (score 8):

For the "ERROR ITMS-4238: Redundant Binary Upload." issue...

**I simply used the Apple Application Loader** (along with ensuring the Version and Build numbers being unique) and it worked perfectly.

It looks like Xcode6 GM have some bugs interacting with iTunes Connect.

Comment: This was the only way I could get my issue solved, thanks. To confirm the bug is still existing in Xcode 6.0.1
When I tried using an agent account I got no errors and was able to upload from Xcode easily unlike when I tried using an admin account.

Comment: I experienced the same thing as @XIII.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is appearing because you have already submitted one binary to iTunes connect(You can check that under the build option in iTunes connect).
I think you need to add version 3.1 in the iTunes and in your code, then try to resubmit app.
Here are the more info:
Go to My Apps - > Click on your apps that you need to submit -> Scroll down and you there you will see **Build** option.
Please see below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, could you attach screenshot where I can see that options? I not see anywhere build options in iTunes connect.

Comment: You login into new iTunes connect you will see Build option below the Contact details.

Comment: Thank you, apparently something else, because I don't see in this place available builds.

Answer (score 1):

Right beside the build logo and version number under [Build] as shown in screen shot above you will see a (-) symbol, use that to delete the build after Rejecting the binary.

Build

```
[      ]
[ Logo ]    1.0.0      (-)
[      ]
```

And don't forget to save the changes before trying to upload a new binary or the error *itms 4238* will persist

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by your developer accout. I had the same issue. My developer account has multiple teams. But the email of this account can only be associated with one iTunesConnect Account. If you want to submit the app which is not related to your own iTunes Connect you should use application loader. In application loader enter the account info which is related to apps iTunesConnect acoount. Then you are raedy to submit your app.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue with Xcode 6.0.1, but I had never successfully uploaded a previous binary. I resolved this by ensuring that the "Version Release" setting (manually or automatically release) was set.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I have  two accounts on XCode. One with two teams (A and B), and the second with only one (B). When I build and try to submit an application for B team,  using first account gives me this error.

However, when I select the second account with only one time, It works without a problem. hope this helps.