# Xcode 6 GM Upload Error: No software found with apple_id at SoftwareAssets

Tags: app-store-connect, xcode6

I am trying to update an app that was rejected for a Crash. I am using Xcode 6 GM release. I have 2 problems:

1̶)̶ ̶I̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶f̶i̶n̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶"̶r̶e̶a̶d̶y̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶u̶p̶l̶o̶a̶d̶ ̶b̶i̶n̶a̶r̶y̶"̶ ̶o̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶n̶e̶w̶ ̶i̶n̶t̶e̶r̶f̶a̶c̶e̶ ̶(̶i̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶n̶o̶ ̶l̶o̶n̶g̶e̶r̶ ̶n̶e̶e̶d̶e̶d̶?̶)̶

1) solved no longer need to set "ready to upload binary" per comments below

2) When I submit the build I receive this error: `No software found with apple_id at SoftwareAssets`

[image]

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: 1) Correct, ready to upload is no longer a thing.

Comment: Cool that answers one question. Thanks!

Comment: I am seeing this as well. @Nathan are you targeting the iOS 8 sdk? I am trying to target the iOS 7.1 sdk.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Any one with any discoveries?

Comment: Apple is investigating the bug https://devforums.apple.com/message/1038978#1038978

Comment: It sounds like apple is investigating this bug RE:Chris, but to answer @process255, I am targeting 7.0...

Comment: I was able to get this to work using Application Loader instead of Xcode 6 GM. The key is exporting after the archive rather than submitting via XCode. Another gotcha is using an iTunes Connect user that has sufficient privileges. I thought developer accounts worked in the past but they don't now. I was able to archive from the iOS 7.1 SDK in Xcode 6 and then upload. No word on approval yet however.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766582/xcode6-goldmaster-submitting-build-failed-with-error/25777918#25777918

Comment: You can add each iTunesConnect account to Xcode via Xcode > Preferences > Account. Then select the appropriate account when you upload your app.

Comment: @Chris suggestion solved my problem. I was getting same error message

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if it's the new intended behaviour or just a bug. But for me uploading only worked when i was registered as a apple developer AND itunesconnect User with the same AppleId.

This Answer [XCode6 GoldMaster submitting build failed with error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766582/xcode6-goldmaster-submitting-build-failed-with-error/25777918#25777918) of Chris helped me, but unfortunately didn't do the whole trick.

I'm a member of different Developer Teams with my single AppleId. Uploading apps only worked for me to the team where i was registered in itunesconnect with the same appleId (Unfortunately you can be a member of different developer teams, but only be a single itunesconnect user with one apple id). Adding the different itunesconnect accounts as described in the linked answer didn't work for me. 
So i created a new apple id and added it as a developer and as an itunesconnect user, then everything worked smoothly.

Comment: This was essentially the fix.. iTunesConnect/Xcode apparently has a problem right now when a developer account != iTunes connect account logins .... Thanks for the Help !

Comment: Does it cost money to add it as a developer?

Comment: Actually i only have developer accounts for companies - there you don't have any extra costs, when adding a new developer. If you are a single developer, you might wanna try Bocaxica answer below - which didn't work for me, but it's worth a try.

Comment: This is utter sh*t from Apple. On one way they won't allow one AppleID to have multiple ItuneConnect accounts, and on the other hand it HAS to be the same AppleID in the developer account and the iTunesConnect. This is ridiculous.. seriously. And we all pay 99€/$ for this backward freaking error.

Answer (score 8):

If you're part of multiple teams, and you need to upload an app to iTunes Connect that's using another Apple ID than your own, you will have to add the Apple ID of the concerning iTunes Connect Account to Xcode.

1. Go to Preferences in Xcode
2. Go to Accounts
3. Add account by clicking the + sign
4. Add Apple ID of the iTunes Connect account you're trying to upload to

When you now upload your binary, you have to choose the team and Apple ID. 
You may see the same team twice in the dropdown, but you will see that they relate to  different Apple IDs.

**Make sure to choose the team that is related to the iTunes Connect Apple ID and your upload will go through.**

Comment: This was the fix for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For people who can't have their iTunes Connect and Apple Developer emails match (member of multiple programs, etc) the solution is to click "Export" in Xcode instead of "Submit" which will generate a signed ipa file, then use Application Loader (link is available in iTunes Connect) to log in with your iTC ID and you can upload it there. Hopefully Apple will fix this issue soon where we can link our iTunes and Developer accounts/emails together, but until then this will have to do.

Answer (score 0):

[Bocaxica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/233046/bocaxica) is correct. I also face same issue while I tried submitting my app. After I selected again my different apple account which had same iTunes id for two accounts, everything went well and app submitted successfully.

[image]