# ITMS-4238 error on submitting to app store

Tags: ios, app-store, xcode6

I'm on xcode 6, and I'm trying to submit an iOS(target:iOS8) app to app store, and I'm getting itms-4238 error.
It says, there is already the same build already, but I've never successfully submitted this app so far. So there is no submitted build on itunes connect.
So I don't know why I'm getting this.

What I'm doing is following:

create an Archive
submit binary from Organizer
I also tried to submit with ApplicationLoader but the result was same.

error I'm getting is this.

**ERROR ITMS-4238: "Redundant Binary Upload. There already exists a binary upload with
build version '1.1' for train '1.0' at SoftwareAssets/PrereleaseSoftwareAsset**

I have set a higher build version 0.1.

But still results in an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981890/getting-itms-4238-redundant-binary-upload-error-no-mater-what-i-change-the-bui

Answer (score 9):

Most probably it will occur the same build version. Mismatch the build version. Check your project build version and itune connect build version

Go to your plist file and change "CFBundleVersion" so if you're uploading version 1.2 change it to 1.2.1 but keep the "CFBundleShortVersionString" as 1.2 so you should have

CFBundleShortVersionString - 1.2 CFBundleVersion - 1.2.1

Archive and submit, then in iTunes Connect you will see all the builds you have submitted for the version 1.2

Comment: More better explanation check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766582/xcode6-goldmaster-submitting-build-failed-with-error