# Submission with Xcode 6 to iTunes Connect causes error ITMS-4088

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, app-store-connect

I need to submit an iPhone app to the iTunes Connect account of my customer, by using Xcode 6.

With Xcode 5, during the submission process, we are requested to provide the iTunes Connect login credential to which submit the app.
It was just needed to ask the customer's team agent setting up an iTunes Connect user account for me.
This process was working fine.

Within Xcode 6 the app submission has been changed and it's not requested for iTunes Connect login. So it seems to be using the default iTunes Connect account corresponding with the Apple id configured in Xcode.

So trying to upload an app for the account of my customer I get the following error: 
"ERROR ITMS-4088: "The organization XXXX does not have permission to modify the application with the Apple Id XXXXXXXXX. Please try again, using an account for an organization with access to this application." at SoftwareAssets"

Someone you already encountered this problem ? Do you have an idea how can I solve it?
Thanks

Edit (Some precision about my settings):
I'm working for several customers and so I configured my Apple accounts as follows:

- I have only one Apple developer Account associated to an Apple Id: my.first@email.com
- my developer account is associated to the developer account of some of my customers when I need to make changes with provisioning for instance. And so signing in to developer.apple.com I have to choose the right team I need to work for. It's relatively easy to do by this way.
- For iTunes Connect I have my main account with the same Id as the Apple Id: my.first@email.com
- When I need to submit an app for a customer it's not the same story as for the developer account. Indeed within iTunes Connect, it's needed to provide a new email each time you need to be added to the account of a customer. So I created several redirections of type my.second@email.com, my.third@email.com...
- For submit an app for a customer with Xcode 5 simply choose the right iTunes Connect account when Xcode invite you to do that in the Organizer's submission process.
- With Xcode 6 there is the error above.

Comment: Quote from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766582/xcode6-goldmaster-submitting-build-failed-with-error   "This is due to the wrong account when you send in the ITC."

Comment: Do you have another account or was your account modified recently?

Comment: Thanks @kdogisthebest for your interest. The issue is not due to recent account modification. I'm aware the build is not sent to the right iTune Connect account, but the issue is that Xcode 6 does not really allow selecting a specific iTunes Connect as previous versions. It only allows configuring Apple Ids what is not the same.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Problem with Xcode 6 is that this one does not request anymore to choose the iTunes Connect account to which the current app has to be uploaded.
Xcode seems now to expect uploading the current app to one of the accounts defined in the Preferences panel. However the Preferences’ account section waits for developer Apple Id and not for iTunes Connect account Id. When I added iTunes email to this section I got errors such as: not valid Apple Id or Apple Id not added to a developer account.
Perhaps a solution could be to add each iTunes Connect Id to the corresponding developer team (developer.apple.com) but it’s very constraining.
Another solution could be to have  and Apple’s enterprise developer account instead of personal account, what would allow to add the iTunes Connect Id to your own developer account but I’m not sure this one could solve the issue because I get a personal developer account yet.

After few researches within Google and documentation, I deduced that either there is a bug within Xcode 6 or it’s now very difficult to use in this case, and I gived up to use it to submit this app.

Instead of Xcode I used the Apple’s Application Loader 2.9.1 which is very ease to use and make the submission faster.
It has been the final answer to my issue.

Comment: This. If you have multiple developer accounts and you don't want to create a new apple ID for each app, this does not work. It's a fundamental issue with the developer portal allowing one Apple ID to be used with multiple dev accounts and iTunes connect requiring a unique Apple ID for each business.

Comment: I've used this approach with Application Loader 3.0 and it worked good for me.

Comment: The key takeaway here if you use a different email address for the Developer Center and iTunes connect: you should 1) use Xcode 6 to export a signed IPA, and have the Developer Center ID added to Xcode's accounts, and 2) use Application Loader to sign in with your iTunes Connect email and use it to upload the exported IPA.

Comment: I agree with you the right way now is to use Application Loader submitting apps. This application is really well done and the process is fast but it should be integrated into Xcode from my point of view.

Answer (score 8):

- in your organizer Press in Export.
- Save for ios appStore.
- Generate Ipa.
- Go to Application Loader (In Xcode-- Open developer Tools)
- double Click in Deliver Your App
- Select IPA.

good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue:

For Team XYZ In iTunes Connect I was an Admin with AppleId A

In the Member Center (developer.apple.com) I was an Admin with AppleId B

Once AppleId A was added to the Member Center as an Admin I was able to successfully submit an app via XCode.

So it seems as though the AppleId for Member Center and iTunes Connect must match for each team.

Hope that helps someone,

Kevin

Comment: thanks for your solution but getting several iTunes Connect accounts I cannot believe that the alone solution is to create as many Apple Ids than iTunes accounts and add them to the Member center developer teams respectively. It will be shortly difficult to manage. it would be quite a step backwards in front of what it's possible within Xcode 5. The solution to use Application Loader seems better for me.