# CFBundleShortVersionString in info.plist must be higher than 1.0

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, info.plist

I uploaded the app in App Store, and now it in "Pending Developer Release" status. But I want give it to testers before release. I have no troubles with internal testers, I gave them access to application without problems. But I have trouble with external testers with the same binary. There is an error:

> CFBundleShortVersionString in info.plist must be higher than 1.0

What should I do, if I don't want to reload binary, because I can lose the "Pending Developer Release" status?

Comment: did u get a solution for this?

Comment: @Lakshay, I resigned.

Answer (score 2):

When you release a new version using Apple's distribution system (i.e. App Store or TestFlight) the version number needs to be higher than the previous release.

If the app is still in testing, it shouldn't have even reached `1.0` yet. Start with `0.1` and increment up to `0.999` as development milestones are reached. Once it's tested and ready for release, make it `1.0`. This is my thinking on the issue anyway; the actual value is not important, however some users may query why a newly-released app has a version number of `1.452`, for example.

Note that the number is not a floating point; instead it's `major.minor` and `major` does not increment when `minor` goes above 9; instead the version becomes `1.10` until you rework it sufficiently that the `major` becomes `2` and the `minor` resets to `0`, and so on.

So to answer your question, change `CFBundleShortVersionString` to `1.1`.

As for `CFBundleVersion`, that should be an integer that increments from `1` whenever a build is performed and source files have changed (again, in my opinion), which can be managed with a script as posted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36007955/299924).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! If I understand you, I need to set CFBundleShortVersionString to 1.1 in Info.plist and reload project binary?

Comment: Re-upload you mean? If so, yes.

Comment: year. but in this way I lose my "Pending Developer Release" status.. It' so strange because the same app is available for internal testers. What is the difference?

Comment: Sorry I don't know the answer to that.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem - uploaded a 0.1(2) release, got full app store review, but when I try to push it for external TestFlight review it tells me the version string must be greater than 0.1