# Incrementing build number Xcode (on last component)

Tags: ios, xcode, bash, shell

I currently have this as a script to auto-increment the build number in my Xcode project:

```
#!/bin/bash
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
```

What this script does is incrementing from let's say `1285` to `1286`.

What I want to do is have it on components: Increase it from `1.0.4523` to `1.0.4524`

The reason I need this is because Fabric and iTunes Connect's Testflight use different notation systems for detecting a separate version and this way I can combine the two and not edit it manually always when doing a build for one and a build for the other.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Simpler to keep app version and build number separately and use Apple versioning

[image]

After add run script link this:

[image]
This script will update your build number during each build for all targets.

Dont forget to setup Apple versioning:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hold the version information outside of the `Info.plist` file in a separate *version file*.  This file is kept under source control.

You then:

1. Read the *version file* to get the major, minor and build numbers.
2. Increment the build number.
3. Update the *version file* to capture the new build number.
4. Format the version string as `major`.`minor`.`buildnum` and write that to the `Info.plist` file.

I do something similar in [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001189/create-version-number-variations-for-info-plist-using-define-and-clang/36007955#36007955), however I use Python, rather than shell script, as it's much more powerful.