# Should I change build version of my app after TestFlight in App store connect?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I built and uploaded my app to TestFlight for testing. I tested, solved some problems, and changed some parts. I want to publish on App Store now, so I archived my app from Xcode, but when I do this process should I change the build version? Because there is a build of my app in App Store Connect as I said. I don't know what should I do it is my app :(

when I try same version I got this error

[image: error]

Comment: You should always update the build version every time you build the project (press `Command`+`B`. Here's a [script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9294933/14351818) that does it for you.

Comment: should I change build version now because I want to submit it now

Comment: yes you have to, if you want the same version then first remove the build from testflight and push it again.

Comment: I removed it there is no build in test flight but I cannot push same version in xcode 

Answer (score 1):

It's okay I solved my problem. There are 2 concepts in xcode build and version. I just changed the build, the version number remained the same.