# Is tehere a way to get my app's last version on TestFlight on console? (with altool etc.)

Tags: ios, terminal, testflight, auto-build

I am trying to create an auto builder for my Unity game and it is works well but every time i have to handle to version manually is there a vay to get test flight version on console?

Comment: Can you be more precise ?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258344/better-way-of-incrementing-build-number) can help you ?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I need to find the last app version on TestFlight via terminal. This is getting version data from local project and increasing it